# For which resolution to design in Android platform?

Tags: android, graphics, resolution

A designer asked me which screen resolution should he design for.. Which one should I choose? (480x800, qHD , ..)?

Edit: Why is it unanswerable? Should I add info about the app?
The app wont be for tablets. I aim for smartphones in this phase.

Comment: this question is not answerable

Comment: @KevinDTimm    Can you tell me why?

Comment: For example (this is not exhaustive) without detailed knowledge about the app and its intended (supported) devices no help can be given.  There are myriad parts to this question, all of which need to be determined before you can pick a resolution to develop to.  The only possible answer, given no information in the original question, would be to design for the smallest possible device that your application could support - and then note that requirement in the app itself.

Comment: Yea I quickly then edited the question and said that the app is for smartphones and not tablets. Regarding your last sentence, you say to design for the smallest possible device. But isnt it the other way around? If you scale a small image to a bigger one, the image isnt clear, but the other way around and its good. So should I design for qHD so that even wvga and smaller devices have good graphics or should I design for the smallest?

Comment: You shouldn't develop for any specific resolution, the Android docs warn you about this all over the place. You might want to adapt your screen layout to the class of device (very small screen <2", smartphone-sized 3"-4", tablets >8"), but even then the actual resolution should be none of your concern.

Comment: @Omar Please check out the Android documentation on [Density Independence](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#density-independence) -- you won't have a problem with blurred images if you follow the advice there, regardless of screen resolution.

Answer (score 5):

Your designer should use vector graphics so you're independent of the actual device resolution, check out [Icon Design Guidelines: Tips for Designers](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html#design-tips):

> Many image-editing programs such as Adobe Photoshop allow you to use a
>   combination of vector shapes and raster layers and effects. When
>   possible, use vector shapes so that if the need arises, assets can be
>   scaled up without loss of detail and edge crispness.

For a (growing) selection of Android screen resolutions, see [this section of "Supporting Multiple Screens"](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#screens-table). That document also details the things to look out for to develop a resolution indepdent app.